# 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to create a view in which the user selects an option from a drop down menu, submits it, and then some data is returned. Specifically, they will select from models in the database and have returned all of the instances of that class. I am using django-tables2 to output the data so that it is sortable, but this is my sticking point.

**Views.py**

```
def output_form(request):
    results = None
    if request.GET.get('browse'):
        selection = request.GET.get('browse')

        class ModelTable(tables.Table):
            class Meta:
                model = selection

        results = ModelTable(selection.objects.all())
        RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 3}).configure(results)

    return render(request, 'projectdb/output.html', {
        'results': results,
})
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET">

    <select name="browse">

        <option>Model1</option>

        <option>Model2</option>

    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form><br/><br/>

    {% if results != None %}
        {% render_table results %}
    {% endif %}
```

The error thrown is as in the title:

**'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'**

I have tried converting the 'selection' unicode to a string, which throws basically the same error (str has no attribute _meta).

I would be very grateful for any help.

EDIT: For clarity, what I am trying to achieve:

**User selects model from dropdown ---> selected model is passed to the table somehow ---> table is instantiated and returned to the page below the dropdown, with the data from the selected model**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model` attribute should reference django model class.

But inside the function `output_form`, `selection` reference a `request.GET.get('browse')`: `str` object.

```
class ModelTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = selection # <----
```

Change the `model` attribute to correctly reference the model class.

BTW, extract the `ModelTable` class definition out of the view function.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm trying to achieve. What I want to do is to be able to pass in the form GET into the table to populate it with the model selected from the drop down list. Hence why the ModelTable is a bit weirdly within the view function! Any ideas how I could do that? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sirrah, Define multiple `Table` classes corresponding to each model class. Then make a mapping from the `selection` string to those `Table` classes.   Use the mapping in the view function to get appropriate `Table` class.

Comment: Ah. I have considered doing this so many times but I thought it would be a big violation of the DRY principle. I am a new coder so I often dont know what is right or wrong. I know my code looks wrong but I didn't want to give up on making an automated solution. Is making multiple table classes really the best way to go about this? Thankyou!

Comment: @Sirrah, You can create a class dynamically using [`type` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type). But that will make your program hard to read. In addition to that, you need to define a mapping from selection names to model classes anyway.

Comment: Looks like I have been batting my head against this wall for hours, and it wasn't even worth it. Ah well, its a good lesson to learn. One last thing, is there a way I can distinguish when it is ok to have repeated code vs when it is not? I'll mark this correct shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @Sirrah, I think there's no absoulte answer for that. Personally, I do DRY as far as it does not hurt readability of the code. But before doing DRY refactoring, you need to have a working code.

Comment: Good advice, I'll remember that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is to translate your `selection` from a string to a model class. To do that, use the `django.db.models.get_model` function, e.g.:

selected_model = get_model('myapp', selection)

IMHO, defining dynamically your table class as you done does not hurt readability.

Comment: This line of code... why didn't I think of it?!! Thanks for your input, looks like I will revisit this view and do some DRY refactoring.