# Updating a model instance via a ModelForm: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

Disclaimer: I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162056/unicode-object-has-no-attribute-meta) and a few other related questions, but either I have not understood the answers or the problems discussed there are actually different.

In my app the user can view an instance of a model **Kurs** or edit it -- I have two separate views for the two actions. The details of the model **Kurs** are as follows:

```
class Kurs(models.Model):
   prowadzacy = models.ForeignKey(User)
   nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   [skipping some fields...]
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.nazwa
   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Kursy"
```

So as you can see it has a **unicode** method and a Meta class.

The ModelForm I'm using is this simple one:

```
class KursForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Kurs
    fields = "__all__"
```

The relevant view is as follows (I don't want to use class-based views now):

```
def editcourse(request, pk):
    kurs_id = pk
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = KursForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/usersite')
    else:
        form = KursForm(instance=pk)

    return render(request, 'polls/editcourse.html', {"form" : form})
```

My urlpatterns contain

```
url(r'^editcourse/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.editcourse, name='editcourse')
```

and I'm calling the view from a page which contains the link

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:editcourse' kur.id %}">EDIT THIS COURSE</a>
```

where "kur" is a **Kurs**. My editcourse.html contains the following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Unfortunately when the user clicks on 'EDIT THIS COURSE', what happens is an **AttributeError 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'** and the last few lines of the traceback are

```
File "[my path here]/views.py" in editcourse
  84.         form = KursForm(instance=pk)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  282.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/forms/models.py" in model_to_dict
  87.     opts = instance._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /polls/editcourse/6/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I add an empty '_meta' class to my **Kurs** model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `editcourse` view, `pk` isn't the `kurs` instance, it's a string with the id (in this case `'6'`).

You need to fetch the instance from the db. The shortcut [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) is useful for this. Note that you should pass the instance to the form in the `GET` and `POST` branches of your if statement.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def editcourse(request, pk):
   kurs = get_object_or_404(Kurs, pk=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = KursForm(request.POST, instance=kurs)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/usersite')
    else:
        form = KursForm(instance=kurs)

    return render(request, 'polls/editcourse.html', {"form" : form})
```